# FFmpeg recording 24 hours, 7 days

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to record a webcam video 24/7 using FFmpeg and I have no idea how to do it. I know it allows me to set the recording time to 24 hours, but does anyone know how to make this recording be continuous?

Answer (score 1):

For taking the image you can use this:

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.avi -vf fps=1/60 img%03d.jpg
```

From the [docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video):

> Output one image every minute, named img001.jpg, img002.jpg,
>   img003.jpg, etc. The %03d dictates that the ordinal number of each
>   output image will be formatted using 3 digits.

But for your case, you need to change the `-i myvideo.avi` to the URL of your streaming.

Check the streaming guide: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide

For capturing from the webcam first find your device, for example in a mac you could do:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""
```

And next, you can do this:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 30 -i "0" -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast out.mpg
```

In case you would like a picture every minute try this:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 30 -i "0" -vf fps=1/60  output-%d.jpg
```

Notice the `fps=1/60`, for every 3 seconds would be `20/60`

Check the [capture guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam) for more details.